# Possible to capture the position of a mobile phone with GPS from an application?

Tags: .net, google-maps, mobile, gps

I want to know if it is technically possible to capture the position of a mobile phone with GPS from an application in the mobile phone. And send this position to a web service to represent the location from a web page.

Does the phone have to have a special feature or a brand / model specific?
Can you write the trace information in a file. Kmz (google earth)?

Currently the management application is a web application framework. Net 1.1 with sql server 2005 back.

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: It would hugely be unnecessary to use Google Earth or KMZ.  Google Maps would be the better choice, and you can just create a point simply though the Javascript API.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's technically possible, as long as the phone has a GPS receiver, and you allow for the times when the GPS receiver cannot determine its position (when the satellite signals aren't strong enough).

Any additional information would be phone operating system (Android, iOS) specific.

Comment: any OS, helpful for me any sample code using any phone operating system.

Comment: @alhambraeidos: Here's an explanation for Android developers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html